# Как написать событие, чтобы оно задерживалось перед тем, как выполниться?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как в коде игры написать событие (с применением if и остальное) чтобы оно задерживалось на n секунд перед тем, как оно выполнится?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep();` или `Task.Delay();`, но прежде чем это делать, стоит почитать про потоки или async/await иначе вы повесите на время паузы все приложение.

Comment: В самом Unity нашел [MonoBehaviour.Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html). Без понятия как он работает. Так что пробуйте!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Thread.Sleep() может выдать слишком большую задержку, и для игр это значимо. Invoke использует рефлексию, что тоже не очень крутою

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я не знаком особо с Unity, может вы и правы. В обычных приложениях C# `Thread.Sleep` и `Task.Delay` всегда отрабатывают точно заданное им значение, не разу еще не сталкивался с тем, что задержка была больше заданной.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В играх задержка на несколько кадров, а это всего каких-то 16.7 * 3 **милли**секунд, - сыграет значение. `Thread.Sleep` **может** заморозить поток на большее время, а может и не заморозить, а в индустрии игр и так много "может", нам еще одного не надо :)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Когда я использую Thread.Sleep (я и до этого знал эту функцию), у меня "крашится" вся игра при запуске. Task.Delay еще не пробовал, но если поможет достигнуть нужного, я благодарен вам заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте о корутинах - это то что вам нужно.

Пример инициализации:

```
StartCorutine(MethodName());
```

Объявление корутины

```
Private IEnumerator MethodName
{
    Debug.Log("Before timer started");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f); // Таймер на 10 секунд
    Debug.Log("Atfer timer finished");
}
```

Comment: Я еще зеленый в C#, но почитаю о данном способе, спасибо!

Comment: Это относится больше к юнити. Это особенности движка. Тема не сложная, нужно только попрактиковаться. Если будут оставаться вопросы то пишите.