# Unity задержка перед определенным событием

Tags: unity3d

Оптимально ли использовать задержку перед определенным событием с помощью Time.deltaTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант по легче и по удобнее. А именно корутины.
[Как написать событие, чтобы оно задерживалось перед тем, как выполниться?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906628/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F/906640#906640)
Думаю это вам поможет

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Нужно не поднимать тревогу и указывать отвеченный вопрос-дубликат, а не отвечать ссылкой на свой вопрос снова и снова.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.